# Sublime text find_under_expand not working in macro

Tags: macros, sublimetext, sublimetext3, code-snippets

While attempting to learn dark-lisp, I tried to write to macro's to wrap a selection with ()'s.

```
something
// run wrap-after
(something )
// run wrap-before
( something)
```

I created my wrap snippets, recorded two macros respectively and assigned key-bindings to the macros.

They look like this

```
[
    {"command": "find_under_expand"},
    { "args": { "name": "Packages/User/snippets/wrap-after.sublime-snippet" }, "command": "insert_snippet" }
]
```

When I run the macro, it doesn't behave as expected.

```
| = cursor
som|ething
// press macro keybinding
som( )ething
// expected
(something )
```

I don't think it matters, but here's my keybinding as well

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+alt+d"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/macros/wrap-after.sublime-macro"}},
{"keys": ["ctrl+alt+a"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/macros/wrap-before.sublime-macro"}},
```

Answer (score 1):

`find_under_expand` seems to not work. I also found it on some [unofficial docs](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/commands.html#cmd-list), but sublime wasn't having it.

You can start to debug these errors further in sublime by bringing up the console: `ctrl+~` on mac. The console gave me `Unknown macro command find_under_expand`.

In this case, you can use `expand_selection` as the command with args.

---

#### Macro:

```
[
    {
        "command": "expand_selection",
        "args": {
            "to": "word"
        }
    },
    {
        "command": "insert_snippet",
        "args":
        {
            "name": "Packages/User/wrap-after.sublime-snippet"
        }
    },
]
```

#### wrap-after.sublime-snippet

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[($SELECTION )]]></content>
    <description>this is a description for your snippet</description>
</snippet>
```